# Wave propagation in inhomogeneous media

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, refraction, dielectric

There is a problem I'm trying to solve for some time now and is about the standard (?) approximation that it is made when one tries to solve the Helmholtz equation in inhomogeneous media, that is

\begin{align} \nabla^2\vec{E} + k^2\vec{E}=-\nabla(\vec{E}\cdot\frac{\nabla\epsilon}{\epsilon})\approx0 \end{align}

where \begin{equation} k^2=\omega^2\mu\epsilon, \qquad \vert\frac{\nabla\epsilon}{\epsilon_0}\rvert\lambda<<1 ,\qquad \lambda =wavelength\end{equation} and only epsilon is a function of position. I have searched all the literature I could find and there is not one that explains why this approximation is valid even though it is widely accepted. I expanded the first equation for the $x$ component of the electric field, namely

\begin{equation} \frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial^2 x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2} +k^2 E_x=\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial z}+E_x\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon}{\partial x^2}+E_y\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon}{\partial x\partial y}+E_z\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon}{\partial x\partial z}-\frac{E_x \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x}+E_y \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial y}+E_z \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial z}}{\epsilon^2}\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x}\end{equation}

It's not at all obvious how the small variation over a wavelength assumption can be used to make the right hand side zero. There are even second order derivatives over epsilon appearing about which we known nothing.

This question was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295867/) before but the answer seems to me to be completely nonsensical. For example, it makes the approximation \begin{equation} \lvert \nabla (\vec{E} \cdot \frac{\nabla \epsilon}{\epsilon})\rvert\approx kE\frac{\nabla \epsilon}{\epsilon} \end{equation} which to me makes zero sense. He just ignored the higher derivatives of epsilon and just assumed without giving any reason that the electric field is of the form \begin{equation} \vec{E}=E e^{jkr} \end{equation} with $k$ being a constant, which is not correct by assumption.

Anyone else who stumbled across this problem?

Comment: "He just ignored higher derivatives..."  Yes, but I also said, *You certainly could not use this approximation where there are abrupt changes in refractive index*. One working definition of an abrupt change would be where the second order derivatives are larger than the first order derivatives. As for assuming the form of the electric field - yes, it would have that form and $k$ would be constant over scales of a wavelength, unless the approximation being considered breaks down. Isn't the assumption actually that $(\nabla \ln \epsilon)\lambda \ll 1$?

Comment: note that this formula $\mathbf E = \mathbf E_0  e^{\mathfrak j k r}$ is incorrect because it implies a plane wave. Instead, it should be $\mathbf E(\mathbf r) = \mathbf E_0 (\mathbf r) e^{\mathfrak j k_0 S(\mathbf r)}$ where $S(\mathbf r)$ is the constant phase wavefront, the eikonal,  and $k_0=\omega/c$ is the free space wavenumber, a constant. see [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744145/what-exactly-is-a-analytical-ray-tracer-in-a-physical-sense/744159#744159)

Comment: Never heard about this assumption on the second derivatives, but I'm inclined to believe you. As for the form of the solution, how do you know it in advance? You assume it even if you haven't shown yet that the right side term is approximately zero. But even if the form is correct, the amplitude and the phase of this (almost) plane wave are functions of position. How do you know that their derivatives are insignificant? Also, in your approximation you assume that k appears in the exponential, while the accepted solution has k0 times the eikonal S. Why is that?

Comment: To answer your question, I saw this problem in Stratton (p. 343) and the assumption he gives is the one I posted divided by the permittivity of space. Given that the permittivity of space is always smaller, it is not equivalent to your assumption.

Comment: Yes, it should have said \begin{equation}\vert\frac{\nabla\epsilon}{\epsilon_0}\rvert\lambda<<1 \end{equation} I corrected it.

Comment: If $|\Delta \epsilon|\lambda /\epsilon_0 \ll 1$, then $|\Delta \epsilon|\lambda /\epsilon \ll 1$, which I believe is the necessary condition, is automatically true.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the RHS of the Helmholtz equation is approximately zero if $(\nabla \ln \epsilon) \lambda \ll 1$ or $\nabla \ln \epsilon \ll k$. In the answer you refer to, I did indeed claim that
\begin{equation} \lvert \nabla (\vec{E} \cdot \frac{\nabla \epsilon}{\epsilon})\rvert\approx kE\frac{\nabla \epsilon}{\epsilon} + E\frac{\nabla^2 \epsilon}{\epsilon} \end{equation}
but where I implicitly neglected the second term and assumed the electric field is represented by $E_0 \exp(i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r})$.

This will be justified if we can use the [slowly varying envelope approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_envelope_approximation), which says that the properties of the waves are changing slowly in space compared to a wavelength. In those circumstances we can say that
$$\nabla \epsilon \simeq \alpha\frac{\epsilon}{\lambda} \simeq \alpha\ k\ \epsilon$$
with $\alpha \ll 1$ and that any second derivatives, are given by
$$\nabla^2 \epsilon \simeq \alpha\ k \ \nabla \epsilon \simeq \alpha^2\ k^2 \epsilon$$

If I now use these latter relations in the original equation above
$$ \lvert \nabla (\vec{E} \cdot \frac{\nabla \epsilon}{\epsilon})\rvert\approx \alpha k^2 E + \alpha^2 k^2 E\ . $$
And if $\alpha \ll 1$, then $\alpha^2 \ll \alpha$ and the second term can be neglected.

That is then the justification for ignoring second derivatives and if indeed $\alpha \ll 1$, then the RHS of the Helmholtz equation is $\simeq 0$ and we are justified in assuming that a wave solution of the form $\vec{E} = \vec{E_0} \exp(i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r})$ will be approximately correct.

Note that this cannot be used if $\epsilon$ or $k$ change significantly over a wavelength.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I wouldn't expect to figure it out that way. I thought that the correct way is to find the general solution of the full equation (with the small term) and show that it converges to the form you assumed given the small variation over wavelength assumption.

Comment: @user1524841 perhaps there is a way to do that...?

Comment: If there is, it should be rather difficult. One cannot just use the fundamental solution of the Helmholtz operator because the wavenumber is a function of position.

Comment: Also, looking again at your solution, it seems to me that equation \begin{equation} \nabla\epsilon \approx \alpha \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda} \end{equation} is a little strange. Since the properties of the medium (permittivity here) do not change much over a wavelength, shouldn't it say \begin{equation} \nabla\epsilon \approx \alpha \frac{1}{\lambda} \end{equation} with alpha much smaller than the wavelength, instead of alpha much smaller than 1?

Comment: @user1524841 The gradient of $\epsilon$ is $\epsilon$ divided by a length, in this case, a length which is much larger than the wavelength - i.e. divided by $\lambda/\alpha$, where $\alpha \ll 1$.  Your version is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: I implicitly assume that alpha has the proper dimensions. The problem with the way you have written it is that, in theory, I can always find a permittivity large enough or a wavelength small enough that your assumption does not hold. At best this should be \begin{equation} \nabla\epsilon \approx c \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \end{equation} where c is some constant representing the derivative of the permittivity at a specific point. Now for alpha much smaller than this ratio (not just much smaller than 1) the entire approximation is zero.

Comment: @user1524841 You said "alpha much smaller than the wavelength" - i.e. you gave alpha units of length. Dimensionally incorrect, since $\nabla \epsilon$ is not dimensionless. If my assumption doesn't hold (which is of course a possibility) then neither is the Helmholtz equation approximately zero. *Your own question* says that $\nabla \epsilon \ll \epsilon_0/\lambda$ is used, which is the same thing written in a different way ! I don't think I can provide any more assistance.